# KeyError if is_scalar(key) and isna(key) and not self.hasnans:

Tags: python, pandas

Hello everyone I am new to Python and I am in a Data Analytics course and am having trouble with one of my problems. The following is the problem, my code, then the error message.

Problem: The company wants to provide a promotional offer in the advertisement of the restaurants. The condition to get the offer is that the restaurants must have a rating count of more than 50 and the average rating should be greater than 4. Find the restaurants fulfilling the criteria to get the promotional offer.

[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fGJY.png)

```
five_star_ratings = data.loc[data['rating']>4]

restaurant_ratings_count = five_star_ratings.groupby(['restaurant_name'])['rating'].count()

promo = restaurant_ratings_count[restaurant_ratings_count['rating']>50].count()

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3360             try:
-> 3361                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3362             except KeyError as err:

5 frames
pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'rating'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3361                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3362             except KeyError as err:
-> 3363                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   3364 
   3365         if is_scalar(key) and isna(key) and not self.hasnans:

KeyError: 'rating'
```

Comment: `print(restaurant_ratings_count)` - how does it look? does it have the key you are condiitioning on in it?

Answer (score 4):

reset index... df.reset_index(inplace = True,drop = True)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It solves the problem if you are trying to index, say, row 0, and the index 0 has been removed. Resetting the index solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

`restaurant_ratings_count` does not contain a column called `rating`.  It is a `Series` object, called `rating`, which has the count of the ratings above 4.  If I understand your assignment, I believe you want

```
restaurant_ratings_count = data.groupby(['restaurant_name'])['rating'].count()
promo = restaurant_ratings_count[restaurant_ratings_count>50]
```

That gives you the names of the restaurants with more than 50 ratings.  (They didn't ask for restaurants with more than 50 5-star ratings, which is what you were calculating.)

### Followup

This produces the restaurant names that have both at least one 5 rating, and at least 50 ratings of any kind.  I produce two Series and then merge them.

```
import pandas as pd

datain = [
        ["McDonalds", 3],
        ["McDonalds", 5],
        ["McDonalds", 5],
        ["McDonalds", 2],
        ["McDonalds", 4],
        ["Carls", 3], ["Carls", 5], ["Carls", 5], ["Carls", 1], ["Carls", 2],
        ["Carls", 3], ["Carls", 5], ["Carls", 5], ["Carls", 1], ["Carls", 2],
        ["Carls", 3], ["Carls", 5], ["Carls", 5], ["Carls", 1], ["Carls", 2],
        ["Carls", 3], ["Carls", 5], ["Carls", 5], ["Carls", 1], ["Carls", 2],
        ["Carls", 3], ["Carls", 5], ["Carls", 5], ["Carls", 1], ["Carls", 2],
        ["Carls", 3], ["Carls", 5], ["Carls", 5], ["Carls", 1], ["Carls", 2],
        ["Carls", 3], ["Carls", 5], ["Carls", 5], ["Carls", 1], ["Carls", 2],
        ["Carls", 3], ["Carls", 5], ["Carls", 5], ["Carls", 1], ["Carls", 2],
        ["Carls", 3], ["Carls", 5], ["Carls", 5], ["Carls", 1], ["Carls", 2],
        ["Carls", 3], ["Carls", 5], ["Carls", 5], ["Carls", 1], ["Carls", 2],
        ["Carls", 3], ["Carls", 5], ["Carls", 5], ["Carls", 1], ["Carls", 2]
]
data = pd.DataFrame(datain, columns=['restaurant_name','rating'])
print(data)

five_star_ratings = data[data['rating']>4].drop_duplicates()['restaurant_name']
print(five_star_ratings)

restaurant_ratings_count = data.groupby(['restaurant_name'])['rating'].count()
print(restaurant_ratings_count)

more_than_50 = restaurant_ratings_count[restaurant_ratings_count>50]
print(more_than_50)

promo = pd.merge(five_star_ratings,more_than_50,left_on='restaurant_name',right_on='restaurant_name')
print(promo)
```

Output:

```
   restaurant_name  rating
0        McDonalds       3
1        McDonalds       5
2        McDonalds       5
3        McDonalds       2
4        McDonalds       4
5            Carls       3
6            Carls       5
7            Carls       5
8            Carls       1
9            Carls       2
10           Carls       3
11           Carls       5
12           Carls       5
13           Carls       1
14           Carls       2
15           Carls       3
16           Carls       5
17           Carls       5
18           Carls       1
19           Carls       2
20           Carls       3
21           Carls       5
22           Carls       5
23           Carls       1
24           Carls       2
25           Carls       3
26           Carls       5
27           Carls       5
28           Carls       1
29           Carls       2
30           Carls       3
31           Carls       5
32           Carls       5
33           Carls       1
34           Carls       2
35           Carls       3
36           Carls       5
37           Carls       5
38           Carls       1
39           Carls       2
40           Carls       3
41           Carls       5
42           Carls       5
43           Carls       1
44           Carls       2
45           Carls       3
46           Carls       5
47           Carls       5
48           Carls       1
49           Carls       2
50           Carls       3
51           Carls       5
52           Carls       5
53           Carls       1
54           Carls       2
55           Carls       3
56           Carls       5
57           Carls       5
58           Carls       1
59           Carls       2
1    McDonalds
6        Carls
Name: restaurant_name, dtype: object
restaurant_name
Carls        55
McDonalds     5
Name: rating, dtype: int64
restaurant_name
Carls    55
Name: rating, dtype: int64
  restaurant_name  rating
0           Carls      55
```

Comment: The problem asks for two conditions for the promotion, show the names of restaurants with a rating >4 and a rating count >50.

Comment: Am I having this problem because the rating column has NaN values? I tried your code is displayed 177 rows and when I filtered the data with a pivot table in excel it on returned 2 restaurant names.

Comment: Without seeing your data, there's no way I could know.  Why are there NaN values?  Perhaps you should do a `dropna` to get rid of them before starting.

Comment: Part of the assignment is missing value detection and treatment. The data set has 1898 rows and of that data 736 ratings were 'Not given'. So early on I used np.nan and changed the data type to float. I didn't think it was a good idea to impute or drop the rows with missing data because those rows had other valuable data worth keeping for other analysis. What should I do?

Comment: Again, without seeing the data, we're just guessing.  For THIS assignment, you don't care about those other columns, so `dropna`  is not going to do any harm.  Right?

Comment: Added a photo link to the post.

Comment: If a "NaN" means there was no rating, then clearly you HAVE to eliminate those rows when counting up the number of ratings.  Right?

Comment: Could I eliminate them for this part only and not affect the original data for the rest of the notebook?

Comment: The `dropna` method by default returns a new DataFrame without the rows.

Comment: Thank you sir I will give it a try!